# USB over RJ45 to USB C

Tags: usb, rj45, usb-c

I am working on an Arcade Stick/Fight Stick enclosure. Internally, the PCB (Brook UFB) runs USB over a standard Ethernet cable, to a Neutrik RJ45 passthrough. I typically then create an RJ45 to USB A cable to use the Arcade Stick on my PC, and I have never had any issues with this in previous builds.

I decided I wanted the convenience of the symmetrical USB C connector. I purchased a USB A to USB C cable, cutoff the USB A end, and wired it to the RJ45. This particular cable has only Red (VCC), Black (GND), Green and White (D-/D+) conductors. After plugging the cable in to my PC's USB C port, the PCB does not power up. When I plug the cable into a USB A port using a USB C to USB A adapter, everything works just fine. What might be going on here? Thanks for any insight you can provide.

For reference, the Brook PCB RJ45 USB pinout is below.

1 VCC

3 D-

4 D+

8 GND

Comment: questions about the use of computer peripherals belong on superuser.com

Comment: @Jasen, this is not about the "use", it is about a device rework for a different connector type.

Comment: it's just a matter of using the correct cables

Comment: @Jasen It's not just a matter of using the correct cables, as the correct cables do not exist - unless you are aware of a 15ft RJ45 to USB-C cable pre-made, this requires a custom made cable. I was most interested in the technical reasoning the cable worked via A to C adapter, but not directly plugged into a C port. Ale..chenski's answer address the issue.

Comment: type C OTG adaptor + regular USB cable gets you there.

Comment: @Jasen It is not as simple as OTGadapter + regular USB cable, since I am looking for USB-C to RJ45, and no such 15ft cable exists. Implying I "Used the wrong cable" is not the same as "Use an adapter + another cable + still do some custom work" and also has no relevance to the original question and why my attempted solution did not work. If you read the post, I already know I can make it work with an adapter. I was interested in the technical details of how to make a clean, custom RJ45 to USB-C without adapters or dongles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rework doesn't work because you used wrong Type-C cable.

The Type-A to Type-C cable is designed to plug its A-end into the standard Type-A USB host PC port. To make it look like a host in Type-C standard the Type-C end is wired as "host". This means that one of CC pin is pulled up to VBUS with 56k resistor, and this signifies that this Type-C end is "host side". This resistor is embedded into Type-C overmold, and you can't access or change it without destroying the connector housing. So when you plug this end into your Type-C PC port, you are connecting USB host to USB host, and your PC port doesn't engage.

You are however making a USB device. Type-C port on USB device must have 5.1k pull-down. If you manage to have your Type-C end with 5.1k pull-down on CC pin, this pull-down will connect with CC pull-up inside your Type-C port, and the PC port will recognize it as a device, and will turn the VBUS on, and everything will be fine.

To manage the correct CC pull-down you either need to find a Type-C plug fixture [like this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/DIY-24pin-USB-3-1-Type-C-USB-C-Male-Plug-Connector-SMT-Type-with-PC-Board/161698476431),

[image]

Or use so-called [Type-C OTG Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012V56C8K), and cut the A-receptacle side:

[image]

This Type-C end has correct pull-downs, but might be a bit short for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I suspected something like this may be going on. I have used USB-C female ports in projects in the past, so I was familiar with the 56k pull-up resistor, but did not know about the 5.1k pull down. Luckily, I have some of those connectors on hand. My concern is, how do I go about making a very sturdy connection? Simply soldering and heat shrink wrapping will not be strong enough, but I've not seen any DIY mold/strain relief connectors for USB C ports.